# Python Commands from Terminal Aren't Working Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, linux, installation

I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong and this isn't a bug, but when I installed blender from the 'blender' repository and have 2.66a running in an Ubuntu 13.10 VM, I got problems with using Python in the console.
After starting blender I get the following warnings:

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
connect failed: No such file or directory
```

After this when I try to type in any Python commands at the terminal, nothing happens.  The `>>>`, suggesting an interactive Python session also don't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running the GUI-less version of Ubuntu?

Comment: no, the gui appears in the background

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use a portable archive from blender.org?

Comment: Same thing happened.  But the console I get with Shift+F4 does work.  Should the interactive python environment automatically start on the terminal from which Blender is started or am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: @Kylamus No,there is no python console in the terminal from which blender is started.

Comment: That'll be my problem then!  What's the best way to work with the Python terminal while using Blender?  Do you have any suggestions?  Do most just dock a terminal at the bottom of the Blender application and work with it from there?

Comment: For the colour management - [read this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/how-do-i-solve-color-management-using-fallback-mode-for-management) for the console [this is an option](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/use-the-terminal-i-called-blender-from-as-my-console) but usually you would use blenders builtin python console. The terminal you start blender from is normally used for debugging output - not interactive use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned by sambler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/commands-from-terminal-arent-working-ubuntu-13-10#comment10119_6339), the terminal from which blender is started is not normally used as an interactive python console. (however [it is possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2918/599))

Usually one uses [the python console built into the GUI](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console).

The python console is an [editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_types) just like the 3D view or the text editor, so you can [arrange your screen layout](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames) however you like to incorporate it with your workflow.

For example:

[image]

You can even [split an editor into a separate window](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames#Opening_new_windows) (as in the kind handled by the window manager).
This can be accomplished by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> on the area splitting corner and dragging, or by selecting the option from the editor areas menu:

[image]

For example:

[image]

Note that you probably still want the terminal from which blender was started open, as any error messages/warnings are printed to stdout and will appear there  (they will not appear in the interface by default, but [there is a workaround](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5394/599)).