# Blender error on startup

Tags: python, opengl, color-management

When I start Blender, I get this error in the CMD:

> COLOR MANAGEMENT : USING FALLBACK MODE FOR MANAGEMENT
>   BLT_LANG_INIT: 'LOCALE' DATA PATH FOR TRANSLATIONS NOT FOUND, CONTINUING
>   AL LIB:  UPDATEDEVICESPARAMS: FAILED TO SET 44100HZ, GOT 48000HZ
>   INSTEAD WARNING! LEGACY WGL IS UNABLE TO SELECT BETWEEN OPENGL VERSIONS.WARNING!BUNDLED PYTHON NOT FOUND AND IS EXPECTED ON THIS PLATFORM.
>
> CURRENT THREAD 0x00001900 :

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**PC Specs:**

- Graphics card: NVIDIA 2GB 610GT
- Ram: 4GB
- Processor: AMD FXX SERIES
- Operating system: Windows 7 Ultimate 64BIT

Comment: What version of blender, where from, and how did you install it? Have you moved blender.exe?

Comment: @ankit instead of reposting the same question, please add more information to your original question using the [edit] link at the bottom of your post. It would help to know what kind of installation you used (MSI install or zip). Have you tried updating the drivers for your video card?

Comment: On https://developer.blender.org/T47239, a similar issue suggests you may have gotten your build from a site other than blender's. Make sure you've downloaded your build from [here](https://www.blender.org/download/). Also, it looks like there's a struggle to use the "fallback mode for [colour] management"; this post addresses this here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/how-do-i-solve-color-management-using-fallback-mode-for-management

Comment: version is 2.77